# CAML Query for sorting Multiple fields not working

Tags: caml-query, jsom, caml-designer

I had written the below line to sort multiple fields using CAML query, But it's not working. Can any one help what's the issue.

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Month' /><Value Type='Text'>"+mymonthvalue+"</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Sub%5Fx002d%5FOrder' Ascending='TRUE' /><FieldRef Name='Order' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");
```

Comment: Check the internal name of the field, Sub%5Fx002d%5FOrder. Moreover, try using CAML Query Builder: https://www.u2u.be/software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned above, it should work with Sub_**x002d**_Order, if not there is some other problem.

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Month' /><Value Type='Text'>"+mymonthvalue+"</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name='Sub_x002d_Order' Ascending='TRUE' />
            <FieldRef Name='Order' Ascending='TRUE' />
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Comment: I was missing 0 at the end of  to Column Name "Order"

Answer (score 1):

Change your field name - the %5F should be an underline. The internal field names use `_x0020_` to represent the space and `_x002d_` to represent the dash.

Comment: I had converted the name from "Sub%5Fx002d%5FOrder" to "Sub_x0020_Order" . But I found no luck

Comment: As the others mentioned, change it to Sub_x002d_Order. You don't have a space, you have a dash.